# How would I define an object that would take the result of using regsubsets?

Tags: r, object

How would I define an object that would take the result of using regsubsets? For example, I want to define a row (or vector) "fitty" of lenght 10 such that it can take 10 results of regsubsets as follows:
Hitters is some data with 20 columns. I want to check which subset best explains Salary in terms of other 19 predictors using 10-fold cross validation set.

```
k=10
f = sample(1:10, nrow(Hitters) , replace=T)
for (i in 1:k){
fitty[i] = regsubsets( Salary~. , Hitters[f!=i,] , nvmax=19) 
}
```

I want to be able to use fitty[i] or fitty[[i]] again. But I need to define fitty apriori, right? How?

This hitters is in package (ISLR) or (MASS)... I am studying (in detail) chapter 6 of ISLR (Intro to Statistical Learning with R).

Comment: Are you looking for a list with lapply? `res = lapply(1:10, function(i){dosomethingwith(i)})`

Comment: Hi Spacedman! I tried what you just wrote but I can't use the information in res[i] for some reason (beyond my understanding). I should be able to use    coef(fitty[9],15) whenever I want. But what you wrote doesn't work.

Comment: If you can edit your question to make it something we can all run then we can probably help you more.

Comment: If you want the 9th item from a list then it should be `fitty[[9]]`

Comment: I just edited the question including more info.